# Eclipse 2018-09 JEE startup error

Tags: 18.04, eclipse

Eclipse JEE , 2018-09 release on Ubuntu Bionic beaver does not work.The marketplace GUI is not rendered.It crashes on exit.JRE is Oracle jre 8 . Pls help. thanks in advance.

The logs show these errors:
Eclipse:3817): IBUS-WARNING **: 23:57:55.555: The owner of /home/gangs/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gObjectClass_finalize
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK._gtk_widget_destroy(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK.gtk_widget_destroy(GTK.java:8625)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.destroyWidget(Widget.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:4358)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:2836)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close(Window.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.close(Dialog.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.okPressed(Dialog.java:953)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.workspaceSelected(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.okPressed(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5051)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4583)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /root/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.9.1.20180912-1601.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://979.fwk4894200:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://979.fwk4894200:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback

(WebKitWebProcess:3869): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:19.287: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3869): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:19.312: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3869): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:19.312: g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
**
ERROR:webkitgtk_extension.c:47:proxy_init: assertion failed: (parentUniqueId != 0)

(WebKitWebProcess:3915): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:44.512: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3915): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:44.513: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3915): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:44.513: g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
**
ERROR:webkitgtk_extension.c:47:proxy_init: assertion failed: (parentUniqueId != 0)

(WebKitWebProcess:3930): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:49.562: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3930): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:49.563: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3930): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:49.563: g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
**
ERROR:webkitgtk_extension.c:47:proxy_init: assertion failed: (parentUniqueId != 0)

(WebKitWebProcess:3945): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:53.056: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3945): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:53.057: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:3945): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:58:53.057: g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
**
ERROR:webkitgtk_extension.c:47:proxy_init: assertion failed: (parentUniqueId != 0)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately gObjectClass_finalize is known bug that has no fix yet and slim chances to be fixed. I suppose you are running 32 bit Linux here. You can follow the history of the bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=527536

The solution can be to switch to 64 bit version of Linux.